# getting access to more UARTs on micro controllers

Tags: spi, uart, interface

I will need to interface a micro controller to some breakout boards that only talk through UARTs, so confronted with the eternal 'need more hardware UARTs' problem.

I have seen 2 kind of solutions out there:

- add a barebone ATmega328P or similar, connected by I2C to the main micro controller, and use it as an UART. Sounds like using a hammer to kill a fly.
- find a dedicated barebone micro controller breakout for doing this, for example:

https://www.instructables.com/id/SPI-to-4-x-UART-Bridge-MULTIUART/

This is a bit the same as using a barebone ATmega328P, but at least I get 4 UARTS. I looked for established shops where to buy these already assembled but could not find. Any suggestions?

- Any other idea? Is there really no hardware bridge I2C <-> UART available as breakouts out there?

Comment: How many UARTS do you need? Xmega128A1U has 8 USART for example.

Comment: 8 UARTs would cover my needs. This sounds great. But the producer page says 'not recommended for new designs', and most importantly, it seems to not be available as DIP package which is more breakout board / soldering friendly, right?

Comment: There used to be quad UART chips like the 16c554 and 68c554, memory serving. I'll bet there are more options like this now. Look up "quad UART" in Google. As I see in an above comment, there appear to be octal UART ICs, as well.

Comment: I just remembered another oldy -- the Motorola 683xx came with a TPU. That baby could do lots of UARTs. But it is probably unobtainable now. But specialized MCUs are boutique, so I'd recommend sticking with external add-on quad UARTs, which are likely to be with us for more time. They've been around for 30 years and likely to hang around a bit longer.

Comment: Are you relaying the data to a computer? If that's the case you could use a Quad-UART FTDI chip: https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT4232H.htm

Comment: No, no computer, only micro controller. But thanks.

Comment: Just get the right MCU with enough peripherals. Doing these in bit-banging software or by hooking up some strange interface IC on other serial bus is utter madness. It's not a hammer to kill a fly - it's using a fly instead of a hammer. Microchip SAMC/SAMD etc for example has some 8 peripherals that you can configure to operate as UART, SPI or whatever you need.

Comment: Can you use programmable logic? This would be trivial in a small FPGA?

Answer (score 3):

There are 7+ mainstream STM32F0 MCUs with 8 USART interfaces. There are several high performance STM32F4/F7 chips with 4 USART + 6 UART (for 10 total) interfaces, and three dozen chips with 4 USART + 4 UART (for 8 total).

I am pretty sure you can find similar options from other manufacturers if you stop looking for DIP package. The adapters from LQFP to DIP are freely available and cheap.

Comment: Discovery boards will set the OP free!  On-board programmer as well.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Discovery boards is hardware version of "bloatware" software. If OP is OK with non-breadboard solution then Nucleo boards is what I'd be looking for. And even those can be tricky to configure for all UARTs available, due to abundance of solder jumpers you have to deal with

Comment: The thing I do NOT like about finding MCUs with the right number of UARTs is that it limits your MCU options and it is selecting boutique parts which may disappear or otherwise lock you into a toolchain and manufacturer. Using external quad UART parts allows growth, development, change, or entirely new products/lines having very different requirements (except for the UARTs) and the use of the internally developed IP to be transferred. Quad UARTs clearly aren't boutique. They've been around for decades and I expect more decades. (That said, Microchip makes their parts *forever*, my experience.)

Comment: The bit rates the OP is looking to handle are not excessive and while I don't why the OP mentions 8, it's possible that the 8 turns into 10 or 12 or 6 for some spin of a product. Using the quads again makes these kinds of choices much easier than having selected a boutique MCU in the first place.

Comment: @jonk First, I did not see any mention of a "product". My impression is that this is a hobby project for which extensibility and lifetime are non-issues. Second, when we are talking about commercial development there are "longevity commitments" available for every single MCU, e.g. up to 10 years in case of STM. And when product comes to its end-of-life usually there are drop-in replacements available.

Comment: @Maple I'm just commenting, not complaining. Don't get me wrong. I just want to make sure the OP (who knows what's going on better than any of us) thinks about all aspects being offered here along with various secondary considerations. In regards "longevity" commitments, I still have products I support that are using Lattice C compiler, Intel linker, which must use the DOS environment old ISA bus hardware just to compile and test. That's 1985 toolsets. I have used a PIC17 from not long after. Microchip still makes it. I have a Microchip tool from 1990. They still support it and make modules.

Comment: @Maple No company I know of, outside of Microchip, offers that kind of support for their ICs and for their professional toolsets. No one. There's only one option for that kind of length of support. Some people may think that 10 years is good. For some products, that's not even close.

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem. There are bridge chips that can be controlled over I2C or SPI and have a UART.

Examples for the phrase "i2c uart ic":

- [SC16IS750/52/60/62](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/75015676.pdf)
- [MAX3107](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/MAX3107.html)
- [XR20M1172](https://www.maxlinear.com/product/interface/uarts/i2c-spi-uarts/xr20m1172) (double UART)

Example breakout: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/32772833676.html

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted. Thank you for pointing to this, in particular the last link (CJMCU-750 SC16IS750 Single UART with I2C-busSPI interface) looks promising.

Comment: @Zorglub29 my guess the downvote was because using chips with slower interface to bridge to _multiple faster interfaces_ is probably the worst possible idea. My advice is to listen to Lunding's advice (in comments to OP) and find right MCU for the job

Comment: I don't think the OP specified the bandwidth. You still could squeeze quite some 9600  baud UARTs on a 400kHz I2C ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also bit-bang a UART interface in software.  This does not require dedicated UART hardware.  Note however, that transmitting on a bit-banged interface takes more time than a hardware interface.

If you use Arduino, this might be of interest to you: 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial

Comment: You are right, that could be a quite good solution. The limitation is that I can only listen to software serial one port at a time, right? So if I am listening to 1 device, and another talks to me, then I will loose the information from the second, right? This may me ok in some cases, but not ideal. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The Arduino Library does not support listening to multiple interfaces at once.  However it is possible in theory, but you would need to code that yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Bit banging is much easier when the bus architecture supports a clock.  It might be a PITA guaranteeing a baud rate while bit banging.  Also, the Arduino environment might be a bit confining for a project like this.

Answer (score 0):

The STM32F413 looks like it has 10 UARTS! https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f4-series.html

Even better for you, it looks like the STM32F413 is available on a Discovery Board, https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-discovery-kits/32f413hdiscovery.html, meaning you don't have to worry about interfacing.

I'll leave it to you to verify that enough UARTS are broken out on the Discovery Board.